# My conn model does not classifies properly for men vs woman problem with my custom dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've working on a men vs woman model with tensorflow but my model has 90% percent accuracy but it is not working properly It give diffrent outputs such for female it give male and so on..

I've working man vs woman model but It is not classifying it properly even if the accuracy in 90%
for female it says male I am new for this library I was to frustrated to deal it. I've diffrent cnn filters,datagmendation can anyone help me on this
dataset url : https://acs-test-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/455.tgz

```
from keras.layers.core.dense import Dense
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib,numpy as np,matplotlib.pyplot as plt
file = tf.keras.utils.get_file('455',origin="https://acs-test-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/455.tgz",untar=True)

dir = pathlib.Path(file).with_suffix("")
print(str(list(dir.glob("*"))))
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  "/root/.keras/datasets/455/training/gender/train",
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(400,400),
  batch_size=64)
val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
   "/root/.keras/datasets/455/training/gender/train",
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(400,400),
  batch_size=64)
# data augmentation
for image,label in train_ds:
  
     image = image
   
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential(
  [
    tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal",
                      input_shape=(400,
                                  400,
                                  3)),
    tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.1),
    tf.keras.layers.RandomZoom(0.5),
  ]

)
img_height = 400
img_width = 400
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
  data_augmentation,
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3),activation="relu",input_shape=(400,400,3)),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),activation="relu",input_shape=(400,400,3)),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
   tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size=(3,3),activation="relu",input_shape=(400,400,3)),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(64,activation="relu"),
   tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation="softmax"),

])
model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(train_ds,validation_data=val_ds,epochs=15)
woman = "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/c4/f6/4d/c4f64dfe3005f1e17b8e99a6f6afb4d2.jpg"
orwom = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin=sunflower_url)

img = tf.keras.utils.load_img(
   orwom, target_size=(img_height, img_width)
)
img_array = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
plt.imshow(image[4]/255,cmap=plt.cm.binary)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(image[4]/255, 0) # Create a batch

predictions = model.predict(img_array)
print(predictions)
score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])

print(train_ds.class_names,
   np.argmax(predictions[0])
)
```

Even if I try with images from diffrent orgin the same problem

```
woman = "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/c4/f6/4d/c4f64dfe3005f1e17b8e99a6f6afb4d2.jpg"
orwom = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin=sunflower_url)

img = tf.keras.utils.load_img(
   orwom, target_size=(img_height, img_width)
)
img_array = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
plt.imshow(img/255,cmap=plt.cm.binary)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(img/255, 0) # Create a batch

predictions = model.predict(img_array)
print(predictions)
score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])

print(train_ds.class_names,
   np.argmax(predictions[0])
)
```